# Error loading tidyverse after installing readxl package

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse, readxl

I downloaded readxl package from CRAN, to read some excel file for processing in R. Unfortunately, I noticed that tidyverse could not load anymore. It kept displaying the error message below:

Error:

> `package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
>    there is no package called ‘readxl’`

Kindly assist please. Many thanks!

Comment: It sounds like readxl possibly isn't installed in the correct folder.

Comment: @ashleedawg: readxl is stored in the same folder that contains all other r packages on my pc. So, I'm at a loss as to what could be the issue here.

Comment: Try to restart R session and just load tidyverse.. If that does not work then mannually delete both folders tidyverse and readxl from your R lib directory and re install in both orders.. something like this worked for me when I faced similiar issue with readxl and XLconnect.

Comment: @JacobJacox: It worked perfectly! Thanks so much. I'm really grateful for your very kind assistance.

Comment: @ashleedawg: Thanks too for taking out time to lend a helping hand. I'm equally grateful